# net core 2.0 entity framework select where datetime add hours

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core-2.0

I am doing an `Net Core 2.0 Application` with `Entity Framework`.

I have to do a select like this.

```
select o.* from orders o
where dateadd(hour,1,o.lastupdate ) > getdate()
```

I know that I can use

```sql
from a in db.Orders
let d = SqlFunctions.DateAdd("hh", 2, a.lastupdate)
```

but I need to do a reference to

```
using System.Data.Entity.SqlServer;
```

in order to use `SqlFunctions` function.

i do not find it in net core 2.0...

How can I do it with net core?

Thanks